# Valuable changes depends on the existence of argument file

Tags: fish

I wrote configuration of fish shell like this:

```
# One or more argument(s) will be given
function run
    set -l src $argv[1]
    set -l var
    switch "$src"
        case *
            set var "$src"
    end
    echo $var
end
```

I expected the first argument is printed in any case if one or more argument is given. However, `$var` becomes `$argv[1]` if file with the same name as `$argv[1]` exists, *otherwise it becomes empty string*.

Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` in `case *` is interpreted as a glob. Quote it if you do not want that.

Answer (score 3):

Faho already answered your question but I wanted to point out that your approach is more complicated than necessary. If you just want to print the first argument if one or more were provided do this:

```
set -q argv[1]
and echo $argv[1]
```

The first statement checks if `argv` has at least one value. The second echoes it if the previous statement returned success (i.e., `$status` set to zero).

Comment: The above code is minimized one, so printing the first argument is not my purpose. But I didn't know such shorter way to check the length of `argv`, so anyway thank you. (And I'll try and make a response to faho's answer in a few days.)